# awk output is acting weird

Tags: bash, awk, output

```
cat TEXT | awk -v var=$i -v varB=$j '$1~var , $1~varB {print $1}' > PROBLEM HERE
```

I am passing two variables from an array to parse a very large text file by range. And it works, kind of.

if I use ">" the output to the file will ONLY be the last three lines as verified by cat and a text editor.

if I use ">>" the output to the file will include one complete read of TEXT and then it will divide the second read into the ranges I want.

if I let the output go through to the shell I get the same problem as above.

Question:
It appears awk is reading every line and printing it. Then it goes back and selects the ranges from the TEXT file. It does not do this if I use constants in the range pattern search.

I undestand awk must read all lines to find the ranges I request.

1. why is it printing the entire document?
2. How can I get it to ONLY print the ranges selected?

This is the last hurdle in a big project and I am beating my head against the table.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a data sample and desired output?

Comment: In the context of your script, `>` is the SHELL command to overwrite a file and `>>` is the SHELL command to append to a file. Neither of them have anything at all to do with awk. Are you maybe trying to write your output back to the same file you are using for input? wrt the awk command - never use range expressions as they make trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then anything even marginally more interesting requires a complete rewrite. If you edit your question to show some testable sample input and expected output we can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

give this a try, you didn't assign `varB` in right way:

```
 yours: awk -v var="$i" -varB="$j" ...
 mine : awk -v var="$i" -v varB="$j" ...
                         ^^
```

Comment: shucks! I did do it correctly but I did not copy and write it to the board correctly. What you listed is what I have. (two computers, the liunx machine is not on the network :(    Same problem

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the typo, you can't use variables in `//`, instead you have to specify with regular `~` match.  Also quote your shell variables (here is not needed obviously, but to set an example).  For example

```
seq 1 10 | awk -v b="3" -v e="5" '$0 ~ b, $0 ~ e'
```

should print 3..5 as expected

Comment: I did not use / /, I used the ~ to match . Also, I have a ton of variables so I am calling them from an array (ergo -v var="$i") etc. They typo was explained below. I am using what Kent had proposed already.  Any advice?

Comment: Please add an example of your input and expected output.  For this and future questions as well.

Comment: is this still locked?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
awk -v var="foo" -v varB="bar" '$1~var{f=1} f{print $1} $1~varB{f=0}' file
```

e.g.

```
$ cat file
1
2
foo
3
4
bar
5
foo
6
bar
7

$ awk -v var="foo" -v varB="bar" '$1~var{f=1} f{print $1} $1~varB{f=0}' file
foo
3
4
bar
foo
6
bar
```

but without sample input and expected output it's just a guess and this would not address the SHELL behavior you are seeing wrt use of `>` vs `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happened. I used an array to input into my variables. I set the counter for what I thought was the total length of the array. When the final iteration of the array was reached, there was a null value returned to awk for the variable. This caused it to print EVERYTHING. Once I correctly had a counter with the correct number of array elements the printing oddity ended.

As far as the > vs >> goes, I don't know. It did stop, but I wasn't as careful in documenting it. I think what happened is that I used $1 in the print command to save time, and with each line it printed at the end it erased the whole file and left the last three identical matches. Something to ponder. Thanks Ed for the honest work. And no thank you to Robo responses.